# How to check jndi bind/unbind status?

Tags: java, queue, jms, bind, jndi

I'm looking for way of checking bind status of object and appropriate jndi name.

For example, I've got some ldap jms queue name:
"/TheRootContext/SomeSubContext/SOME.QUEUE.NAME:queue"

I need to check that appropriate queue exists and it is binded with passed name.

What will be the correct way to check "bind status"?

I see such algorithm:

1. Perform jndi lookup to ensure that provided name exists.

   Object obj = ctx.lookup("/TheRootContext/SomeSubContext/SOME.QUEUE.NAME:queue");
2. **%I don't know what to do next%**, but suggest something like checking that:

   obj != null && obj instanceof javax.jms.Queue

Am I correct? What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely if object is not found [lookup](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) will throw a [NamingException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingException.html) in 1. You need to either catch an exception or try to use [list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#list%28java.lang.String%29) method to check if object exists.

Comment: Yes, I'm catching [NamingException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingException.html) in the code, but this tells me only about naming problems, but nothing about bindings. For example, it is possible that ldap name exists but object doesn't. And in that case I will not get any [NamingException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingException.html). As I can see, [list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#list(java.lang.String)) method enumerates only names bound to context.@Superfilin

Comment: May be I should use [listBindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#listBindings(javax.naming.Name)) method? But it seems like very heavy mean, to iterate through all bindings. May be exists more lightweight way? @Superfilin

Comment: But you can specify your target name as an input to list or listBindings. In best case it will return 1 and in worst 0 beans. I don't think it's more heavy than lookup.

Comment: Also I don't think you can bind a name to null. At least to my knowledge not all JNDI providers allow that. So, NamingException will be thrown in that case as well.

Comment: If null binding is possible with your JNDI provider, then the check that you've done in #2 is just enough.

Comment: I'm not shure if my target JNDI provider allows nulls. I know only that it is ldap-based. So for a now, best found way is to use [listBindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#listBindings(javax.naming.Name)) method. But as I understood, it takes **context** name as input, and returns all **objects** in that context. So it still might be heavy, if there are dozens of objects in context. @Superfilin, thx!